# Javascript dictionary to html data string

Tags: javascript, html

I need to convert an javascript dictionary into an html string, that is parsed by jquery into an object.

```
<div data-options="apple:0,name:'myname'">
```

Note that strings must be enclosed with single quotes and it does not matter whether the key is enclosed with single quotes or not.

What I came up with is this, but as this is used to process quite a large page, I wondered if there is a more efficient way of doing this ?

```
function dic2str(obj){
 return JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/"/g,"'").slice(1,-1)
}

dic2str({"apple":0,'name':"myname"})
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to go with valid JSON and use single quotes in the HTML instead ?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with setting an attribute that contains quotes in a live DOM? If anything serializes the html again it would just have to escape them..

Comment: Just `urlencode` the string after you `JSON.stringify(obj)`, or add object as element `data` with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

test naturally:

```
var json = {apple:0,name:'myname'};

var obj = {x: 5, y: 6};
var objToText = JSON.stringify(json);

var text = '{"x": 5, "y": 6}';
var text2 = '{"apple":0,"name":"myname"}';
var textToObj = JSON.parse(text2);
```

now application:

```
var data = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('data-options');

//this    
var createJSON = "'{"+'"'+data.replace(/[:]/g,'":').replace(/,/g,',"').replace(/'/g,'"')+"}'";
var cJSONstring = createJSON.toString().slice(1,-1);
//or this
var createJSON2 = "{"+'"'+data.replace(/[:]/g,'":').replace(/,/g,',"').replace(/'/g,'"')+"}";

var dataToObj = JSON.parse(cJSONstring);
var dataToText = JSON.stringify(dataToObj);

console.log(dataToText);
```